# How to tell if page is being called from a fetch()?

Tags: javascript, php

With jQuery the Ajax function sets the header `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` , so with PHP I could do:

```
if(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') === 'XMLHttpRequest')
{ ... }
```

And this will tell me the page has been requested using Ajax.

Now I'm wanting to change the `Ajax` function to `fetch()`. I've looked through the default headers that it sets and I can't find anything that I can use to to tell if the request is being sent from a fetch.

I could set the header myself:

```
fetch('/get/login', {
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'fetch',
    },
})
.then(function(response) { ... }
```

However it isn't ideal to be writing that header out for every fetch. What are my options here? Is there a better way to tell if the request is being made through a fetch?

Comment: Append a parameter to URL that acts a flag to indicate this is how it was retrieved. `fetch('/get/login?fetch', {`

Comment: actually, expecting the header to exist all is expecting the wrong thing (there is *zero* guarantee that jQuery even adds that header). If you need to filter based on the method you're calling data from, you'd kind of doing web content serving wrong, but if you absolutely must, just add that header yourself, and make a function that you call that wraps the `fetch` call and the header binding so you don't call `fetch` but that function instead, so you have one function you need to update, ever.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing else you can rely on.

Theoretically you shouldn't give your server different behaviour depending on request method; that should be orthogonal to the content defined by your system's back-end.

But, if you're desperate, I quite like your existing solution; you could wrap it in a function for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are relying on the client side to pass the data, couldn't you pass a POST variable inside body? Passing a header via javascript is no more secure than simply passing an additional field. (https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)

```
fetch('/get/login', {
    body: JSON.stringify({
        source: : "fetch"
    }),
})
.then(function(response) { ... }
```